# update query php

Tags: php, sql

I have this function:

```
function updateinfos($id) {
    parametrs();
    $Log_query = mysql_query("SELECT max(recent) FROM song") or die(mysql_error());
    $Res_user = mysql_fetch_array($Log_query);
    $max = $Res_user[0] + 1;
    $Log_query2 = mysql_query("UPDATE song SET recent = '$max' AND number = number + 1 WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I have a problem in the query update, because it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no i don't get any error

Comment: Did you check the value for `$id`?

Comment: `recent = '$max', number = number + 1`

Comment: yes i check it and it is fine

Comment: I would recommend not using the deprecated mysql functions and using mysqli instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the syntax for UPDATE wrong.

```
UPDATE song
SET   recent = '$max' AND number = number + 1
WHERE id = '$id'
```

By using AND, you're making a boolean expression, not setting the value for two columns.

You should write an UPDATE statement that changes multiple columns like this:

```
UPDATE song
SET   recent = '$max',
      number = number + 1
WHERE id = '$id'
```

In other words, use a comma, not AND.